# NuGet package: Copy DLLs to subdirectories in buildoutput

Tags: nuget

I want to create a NuGet package that copies the DLLs into a subdirectory of the output directory.

This is what the folder structure of my package looks like:

- Package root

  - lib

    - net48

      - x64

        - First.dll
        - Second.dll
      - x86

        - First.dll
        - Second.dll

The DLLs should be copied to the respective subdirectory in the output folder as follows:

- Output directory

  - x64

    - First.dll
    - Second.dll
  - x86

    - First.dll
    - Second.dll

I have tried the files attribute in the nuspec file:

```html
<files>    
  <file src="lib\net48\amd64\*.dll" target="amd64\" />
  <file src="lib\net48\x86\*.dll" target="x86\" />
</files>
```

When building the package the following warning appears for each DLL I use:

> WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'amd64\First.dll' is not inside
>   the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the
>   package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if
>   it needs to be referenced.

Neither the subfolders are created nor the DLLs are copied into the output folder after I restored all packages.

How can I configure the nuspec file so that the DLLs are copied into the subfolders? Do I need an install.ps1 script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **.NET Core (and .NET 5)** projects. And packaging one component with multiple project DLLs. Can do this by modifying prject files.

So if you also have .NET Core projects add the following section to your `.csproj` file (to the project which should be packaged) to package DLL, **change the DLL names and path as you need it**.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_PackageFiles Include="$(OutputPath)\First.dll">
    <BuildAction>None</BuildAction>
    <PackagePath>x64</PackagePath>
  </_PackageFiles>
  <_PackageFiles Include="$(OutputPath)\First.dll">
    <BuildAction>None</BuildAction>
    <PackagePath>x86</PackagePath>
  </_PackageFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```